# How to mute other flash objects on the page with ActionScript or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, actionscript, flash, volume

Is there any way to mute other flash objects on the same page with ActionScript or Javascript? I can understand if this would be a security issue but my flash does have a user-initiated mode which takes over the screen and I was hoping this might be an exception where it's clear it has full priority for the user.

Comment: Do you have access to the objects' source (.fla or .as)?

Comment: No, not for the other SWFs on-page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exposing internal controls in a Flash movie is up to the programmer who writes it. If they haven't exposed an external mute/volume control and have documented it, you're out of luck. There is no universal API that can be called.

Answer (score 1):

Yes for security reasons, you cannot change parameters in other swf objects on the page, except they allow you to do this. In case if all the swf objects created by you, you can  create mechanism with js were user interaction with one swf object send events to all other swf object and they change their state. But you cannot do this with 3rd parties apps.