# How to mute all adobe flash video using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I am working with a website which content some  video . These video are playing using html 5 video . In time of playing video some advertisement are injecting . But problem is these injected advertisement are flash video  . My job is mute to these advertisement video . Please  anybody here help me out how i will mute all flash video using java Script .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mute other flash objects on the page with ActionScript or Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261973/how-to-mute-other-flash-objects-on-the-page-with-actionscript-or-javascript)